# HTTP Status 404 rest url mapping error pagination next

Tags: rest, grails, pagination, urlmappings.groovy

I have a list.gsp that displays list of items which is restful. It displays well but It gives me error when I click next or page no. My mapping is:

```
"/request/list/$sort?/$order?/$max?/$offset?"(controller:"request"){
            action = [GET:"list"]
           }
```

My view pagination is:

```
   <div class="paginationlayer">
        <span >
         <g:paginate next="Next" prev="Back"

              total="${ total }" /></span>

      </div>
```

I tried using name url mapping like this:

```
   name requestURL: "/list/$sort?/$order?/$max?/$offset?"{
            controller = 'request'
            action = 'list'
        }
```

and out some mapping in the view like this `mapping="requestURL"`, I even added params in the pagination, or hardcoded params like offset, max etc but still the same.

but still it gives me HTTP Status 404 when I click "next" it seems that the url loses its map and becomes something like this : `http://localhost:8081/client/request/%5BGET%3Alist%5D?offset=10&max=10&order=desc`

Answer (score 1):

as basic as it may sound, the solution was to put action="list" to the pagination. Didn't occur to me coz all my paginations work with out it.

```
 <span class="gadgetNumber">
         <g:paginate next="Next" prev="Back"
        maxsteps="0" action="list"    
              total="${ printRequestInstanceTotal }" /></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to list all possible parameters in `UrlMappings.groovy`: whatever you may need will still be available via the `params` object or via action method attributes.

Please try rewriting the url mapping as

```
"/request/list"(controller:"request"){
        action = [GET:"list"]
}
```

This will probably resolve your issue and save us the (possibly considerable) effort of determining why exactly your URL mapping isn't being accepted.

Comment: my mapping doesn't have a problem as mentioned until pagination, the params may or may not be there, yes, but the code above was being used in requestserver, and not request client that is calling the restful svc (passing the params).